# Firebase Analytics for Flutter Doesn't Track Event Until resetAnalyticsData() Call

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-analytics

I see no data in Realtime or DebugView in Firebase Console until I call **FirebaseAnalytics#resetAnalyticsData()**.
There seems nothing special in debug output with -FIRDebugEnabled parameter. Events go as usual.

I use 7.0.1 version of firebase_analytics dependency. Tested both in iOS Simulator and on physical device.

Minimal code snippet:

```
final analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();
// have to do: await analytics.resetAnalyticsData();
await analytics.logEvent(name: "test_event");
```

Why could this happen?

Comment: Hi, did you find out the reason behind this issue? I was facing this problem too since my last flutter upgrade.

Comment: @Zane, I don't really remember if I made something special to solve this. I have just checked the working code and it looks like following: analytics = FirebaseAnalytics(); analytics.setUserId(userId); analytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);. After that I log events.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried setting the user Id and collection enabled but it still doesn't work. May I know what version of Flutter, Firebase Core and Firebase Analytic are you using?

Comment: I don't support the app anymore so the versions are not the latest: Flutter 1.22.6, firebase_core: 0.7.0, firebase_analytics: ^7.0.1